# Symmetry of points on the unit circle (solved in comments)

Tags: group-theory, geometry, permutations, rotations, symmetry

There are $n$ points on the unit circle,

$\pmb{r}_{j} = (\cos[\theta_{j}], \sin[\theta_{j}])$.

For every pairs of points ($j$, $k$), the following relation is satisfied,

$\pmb{r}_{j} \cdot \pmb{r}_{k} = \pmb{r}_{\sigma_{1}(j, k)} \cdot \pmb{r}_{\sigma_{2}(j, k)}$,

where

$[\sigma_{1}(j, k), \, \sigma_{2}(j, k)] \ne [j, k]$

$[\sigma_{1}(j, k), \, \sigma_{2}(j, k)] \ne [k, j]$.

In other words, there is no unique angle amongst the ${n \choose 2}$ angles subtended by pairs of points and the origin. What does this imply about the symmetry of the points? $n$ points possessing some rotational symmetry satisfy the constraints. Is rotational symmetry necessary for the constraints to be satisfied?

Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: If you take 4 of the 5 vertices of a regular pentagon, wouldn't those satisfy the criteria?

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment. Yes, four of the five vertices of a regular pentagon would work. Those points are symmetric w.r.t. reflection through a plane passing through the origin and the removed point, so there is still some symmetry there. Can you think of an example with no symmetry (reflection and mirror)?

Comment: Surely you can take a regular n-gon for some large n and remove 3 points in such a way as to break the symmetry? I think 7-3=4 points is minimal (take away those indexed 0, 1, 3, leaving 2, 4, 5, 6).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.